# Access Ruby on Rails component in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this component:

```
  <%= check_box_tag 'delivery_charge', "1", true %>
```

and need to find it in javascript:

```
  check = document.getElementById("delivery_charge").value;
```

It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

yes, but being a checkbox you might want to use

```
check = document.getElementById("delivery_charge").checked;
```

Comment: I try, but does not work. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null"